# How to to avoid appearing once closed by user

Tags: jquery

here is the link : http://newsletter.ihomegym.net/Untitled-3.html

even after I click the close button, on reload it appears again. can I have some help for this please.

So that once closed , should not appear again.

Comment: You will have to implement something on the server side that can remember state. jQuery alone won't do the trick unless you use cookies.

Comment: That bar kind of looks familiar... but I can't remember where I saw it last...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting a cookie when you close the banner and then checking that cookie value before popping up the banner?

For functions to manipulate cookies, you'll have to install this plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 1):

you have to make ajax request (or set cookie via javascript) to your server to remember that this notice should not show again.

simplies way:

```
$("#hidden").load('hide.php');
```

//hide.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['hideNotice'] = true;
?>
```

//notice_page.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['hideNotice']) {

?>
<div id='notification' style="display: none;"> 
    2012 Powertec Spokesmodel Search - Do you have what it takes? - <a href="http://mag.powertecfitness.com/2011-powertec-spokesmodel-search/" style="color: blue">Click Here</a> 
    <span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss this notification">x</a></span> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#notification").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".dismiss").click(function(){
    $("#notification").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});

</script> 

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sure. But I know only PHP as server-side programming language

Comment: @Tomm: Yes it would. But this is just example how it COULD be done